# Launch multiple suspend fun

Tags: coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I created a `TextWatcher` extension to listen to text updates with debounce. I wrapped the `TextWatcher` into a `callbackFlow` which offers the text input through `Flow`.

The issue is that calling `collect()` suspends the processing and I need to register it for multiple `EditText`. Is calling multiple `launch` inside the `scope` the right way correct?

```
private fun initListeners() = lifecycleScope.launch {
        launch {
            edittext_taskdetail_title.textChangedFlow()
                .collect { text -> viewModel.updateTitle(text) }
        }

        launch {
            edittext_taskdetail_description.textChangedFlow()
                .collect { text -> viewModel.updateDescription(text) }
        }
    }
```

This is the extension:

```
fun TextView.textChangedFlow(): Flow<String> {
    val flow: Flow<String> = callbackFlow {
        val listener = object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {}

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                offer(s.toString())
            }
        }
        addTextChangedListener(listener)
        awaitClose { removeTextChangedListener(listener) }
    }

    return flow.debounce(TEXT_UPDATE_DEBOUNCE)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is acceptable I think but here's an alternative.

```
private fun initListeners() {
    edittext_taskdetail_title.textChangedFlow()
        .onEach { text -> viewModel.updateTitle(text) }
        .launchIn(lifecycleScope)

    edittext_taskdetail_description.textChangedFlow()
        .onEach { text -> viewModel.updateDescription(text) }
        .launchIn(lifecycleScope)
}
```

I does pretty much the same thing except, if one of them fails for some reason, the other one won't be cancelled immediately.